# Minimization of Trace(XS) subject to [X,I;I,S]>=0

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have the following trace minization problem

$$
 \min_{X,S\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} \text{Trace}(XS)\\
\text{subject to }
\begin{bmatrix}X&I\\I&S\end{bmatrix}\geqslant 0,\\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~X=X^T,S=S^T
$$
Here $I$ denotes the identity matrix of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Seems that the minimum value of the problem is $n$, but I cannot prove it. Any help are appreciated!

Comment: Can you precise what are the variables? $X$ and $S$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By $\ge$ do you mean "definite semi-positive" ?

Comment: $X,S$ are the variables, and $\geq$ means "positive semidefinite".

Comment: Sorry, the problem should be udpated, $2n$ should be changed to $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
Z = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B^T & C \end{pmatrix}.
$$
The [Schur complement characterization of block PSD matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) says that
$$
Z \geq 0 \iff A \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad C \geq B^T A^{-1} B \quad \text{and} \quad (I-AA^{-1}) B = 0
$$
and
$$
Z \geq 0 \iff C \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad A \geq B C^{-1} B^T \quad \text{and} \quad (I-CC^{-1}) B^T = 0\,
$$
where $A^{-1}$ denotes the generalized inverse if $A$ is not invertible.

In the setting of your question the $(I-AA^{-1}) B = 0$, $(I-CC^{-1}) B^T = 0$ conditions imply that $X$ and $S$ are invertible and so $X>0$ and $S>0$, i.e., $X$ and $S$ are both positive definite. Fixing $X$ and optimizing first over $S$, the condition $C \geq B^T A^{-1} B$ tells us that $S\geq X^{-1}$ and so
$$
\mathrm{Tr}[XS] = \mathrm{Tr}[X^{1/2} S X^{1/2}] \geq \mathrm{Tr}[X^{1/2}X^{-1}X^{1/2}] = n. 
$$
Thus for any fixed $X$ the objective value is lower bounded by $n$ (and is achieved by $S = X^{-1}$) and so completing the optimization by optimizing over $X$ we also find $n$.

Comment: Understood. Thank you, Youem, Rammus, and  Ben Grossmann.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,S)$ be a feasible solution,

I am going to start by proving that $S$ is strictly positive, indeed for $u\in mathbb R^n $$u^TXu + 2t \left(u^Tu\right) + t^2u^TSu =
\begin{bmatrix}
u^T & tu^T
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X & I \ I & S\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u \ tu\end{bmatrix}\ge 0,\quad \forall t\in \mathbb R
$$

So $$
u^TXu u^TSu \ge \left(u^Tu\right)^2
$$

So $S$ is strictly positive.

We can write $S = R^TR$ (since is a definite matrix). For $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^n$

$$x^TXx + 2t \left(x^TR^{-1}y\right) + t^2y^Ty = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x^T & ty^T\left(R^T\right)^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X & I \\ I & S\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ tR^{-1}y\end{bmatrix}\ge 0,\quad \forall t\in \mathbb R
$$

So by taking $t = - \frac{x^TR^{-1}y}{y^Ty}$, $$\left(x^TXx\right)\left(y^Ty\right) - \left(x^TR^{-1}y\right)^2\ge 0\quad \implies y^T\left(x^TXx\right)y \ge y^T\left(R^{-1}\right)^Txx^TR^{-1}y$$

So $$\left(x^TXx\right)I \succeq \left(R^{-1}\right)^Txx^TR^{-1} = \left(\left(R^{-1}\right)^Tx\right)\left(\left(R^{-1}\right)^Tx\right)^T$$ So $$x^TXx \ge \left(\left(R^{-1}\right)^Tx\right)^T\left(\left(R^{-1}\right)^Tx\right) = x^TR^{-1}\left(R^{-1}\right)^Tx = x^T\left(R^TR\right)^{-1}x = x^{T}S^{-1}x$$

So $$X\succeq S^{-1} \implies RXR^T \succeq R^TS^{-1}R = I \implies \text{Tr}(XS) = \text{Tr}(XR^TR) = \text{Tr}(RXR^T) \ge \text{Tr}(I) = n$$

Comment: It is not true that $X \succeq S^{-1} \implies XS \succeq I$. It is true, however, that $X \succeq S^{-1} \implies S^{1/2}XS^{1/2} \succeq I$, which is sufficient for your final step.

Comment: @BenGrossmann indeed you are right.

Comment: Also, you assume that $S$ is strictly positive definite, which requires proof. One approach to showing this is to show that $v^TSv > 0$ when $v \neq 0$ by considering the conjugate matrix
$$
\pmatrix{v & 0\\0 & v}^T \pmatrix{X & I\\ I & S} \pmatrix{v & 0\\0 & v} = \pmatrix{v^TXv & v^Tv\\ v^Tv & v^TSv}.
$$

Comment: Ok I will add a proof of that.

Comment: The last step, why $S^{1/2}XS^{1/2}\geq I $ implies $\text{Tr}(XS)\geq \text{Tr}(I)=n$? @Ben Grossmann

Comment: @LostBird If $Z \geq 0$ then $\mathrm{Tr}[Z] \geq 0$. Or more explicitely, if $A \geq B$ then $A-B \geq 0$ so $\mathrm{Tr}[A-B] \geq 0$ and therefore $\mathrm{Tr}[A]\geq \mathrm{Tr}[B]$.