# Minimize Trace(VX+WS) subject to [V,I;I,W]>=0; [X,I;I,S]>=0

Tags: convex-optimization, control-theory, trace, positive-semidefinite

Define
$$
    \mathcal{K}(A,B)=\begin{bmatrix}A&I\\I&B\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix with proper dimensions,

I have this optimization problem:

$$
    \begin{aligned}
        \min_{X,S,W,V}&\text{Trace}(VX+WS) \\
        \text{subject to }& \mathcal{K}(X,S)\geq 0\\
        & \mathcal{K}(V,W)\geq 0\\
        &V=V^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\\
        &X=X^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\\
        &W=W^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\\
        &S=S^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\\
    \end{aligned}
$$
Seems that the analytic minimum of the problem is $2n$, yet I failed to show that. Any help is appreciated!
$\geq$ means "postive semidefinite".

Comment: Shouldn't this just work using the same method presented in the answers to your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4251064/minimization-of-tracexs-subject-to-x-ii-s-0)?

Comment: They seem different, I am unable to do that, please enlight me.

Comment: You're right, I misread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimizing first over $X$, we know from an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4251227/191112) to your previous question that the positive semidefinite constraints imply $X \geq S^{-1} > 0$ and so we find that after minimizing over $X$ the objective function becomes
$$
\mathrm{Tr}[VS^{-1} + W S].
$$
Using the same logic, after minimizing over $V$ we arrive at
$$
\mathrm{Tr}[W^{-1}S^{-1} + W S] = \mathrm{Tr}[W^{-1/2}S^{-1} W^{-1/2}  + W^{1/2} S W^{1/2}].
$$
Writing $Y = W^{1/2} S W^{1/2}$ the problem is then equivalent to
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\min \quad\mathrm{Tr}[Y + Y^{-1}]\\
&\mathrm{s.t.}\qquad Y>0
\end{aligned}
$$
Indeed for any $Y>0$, $(X,S,W,V) = (Y^{-1},Y, I, I)$ is a feasible point of the original problem such that $Y = W^{1/2} S W^{1/2} > 0$. Conversely $W^{1/2} S W^{1/2} > 0$ as $S > 0$ by the constraints of the original problem. Thus we need only solve this final problem.

Let $\{\lambda_i\}_i$ be the eigenvalues of $Y$. Then by the spectral theorem the problem is equivalent to
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min& \quad\sum_i \lambda_i + \frac{1}{\lambda_i} \\
\mathrm{s.t.}& \qquad \lambda_i > 0 \qquad \text{for all i}
\end{aligned}
$$

We can minimize each term in the sum separately and it is not difficult to show that it is minimized at $\lambda_i = 1$. Thus we have the objective value is $\sum_{i=1}^n 2 = 2n$.

Note that this can be achieved in the original optimization by choosing the feasible point $(I,I,I,I)$.

Comment: The first step,  minimizing over $X$, can you be more specific? @Rammus

Comment: It follows the exact same logic as I gave in the answer to your other question. Use the fact that the PSD constraint implies $X\geq S^{-1}$ to lower bound the trace.

Comment: Finally, got it. $\text{Tr}(V^{1/2}XV^{1/2})\geq \text{Tr}(V^{1/2}S^{-1}V^{1/2})$. Thank you.